# Upload and edit image node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, image-uploading

I'm using Mean.js, and I'm looking for a stack framework/library implementation for the client-side and server-side for editing and uploading images using JavaScript and Node.js.

Thanks :)

Comment: cool. let us know when you've found one and started playing with it, but got stuck on code that you feel should work, but doesn't? Stackoverflow is not for "what should I use?" questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html), which runs on top of jQuery to do the client side editing and uploading.

[Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) is light-wide module that parses most image formats on the server end.